# Windows Sandbox, malvertising flags appearing in host

Tags: windows-10, windows-sandbox

months ago I started visiting a website that every time I visited it gave me dozens of flags in my antivirus due to some advertisements on the site that gave the "malvertising" flag.

So I started visiting it inside the Windows Sandbox environment to avoid having continuous problems and flags on my host and it worked for months.

Yesterday when I visited the same website inside Windows Sandbox, it started giving me dozens of "malvertising" flags on my host antivirus. I thought Windows Sandbox was completely separated from my pc, how is it possible? Are those flags a danger?

Comment: You could use a decent adblocker & stop the issue from arising at all.

Comment: Sandbox is not immune to you visiting the same site inside Sandbox.

Comment: @John I stopped visiting the website on my host but only visiting it through Windows Sandbox. Looking forward to an explaination as I am not an expert.

Comment: You used the website on both environments so some cache or cookie may have caused this

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Sandbox is built on top of Windows. It is allocated RAM
by Windows, accesses the disk via Windows, and so even the internet.

This means that everything that is done inside the Windows Sandbox
is seen and controlled by the anti-virus of Windows, which might
be Windows Defender in your case.

That's why you can get warnings from Windows about your actions inside
the Sandbox.

You will get less warnings, because although you will be reading from
Windows folders and files, any writing that you do is directed to temporary
storage which will be wiped out when the Windows Sandbox is closed.

You can still get infected when working inside the Windows Sandbox,
just that any such infection will not (hopefully) be able to break out
of the Sandbox into the real Windows.